# Change table contents depending on link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have 2 HTML tables. I'm trying to change the contents of the second table depending on what link is pressed in the first table.

Below is the code that populates the first table:

```
$.each(tableResults, function () {
  $('#table1 tbody:last-child').append('<td>' + this + '</td>'); 
});
```

And below is the code that populates the second table:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var tableName = 'databaseTable1';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/api/Dynamic?table=' + tableName, 
    dataType: 'Json',
    success: function (tableResults) {
      $.each(tableResults, function (index, value) {
        if ($('#table2 th:last-child').length === 0) {
          $('#table2 thead').append('<th>' + value + '</th>');
        } else {
          $('#table2 th:last-child').after('<th>' + value + '</th>');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see the tables are populated dynamically. I need to know how to turn each value in the first table into a link that'll change the variable `tableName` into the value selected.

The page should then refresh and display the data from the selected table. If it helps my program has an `F#` back end.

Also on a side note, does anyone know how I could set `tableNames` default value to the first value in `table1`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the `tableName`s in the attribute of the trigger element (such as `a`). Then, when the user clicks on this trigger, get the `tableName` from the attribute using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

I don't know your response so in my example there is a dummy one.

(Click on any line and see the `tableName` in the log.

```js
var tableResults = [
  {
    name: 'dynamicTable1'
  },
  {
    name: 'dynamicTable2'
  }
];

$.each(tableResults, function () {
  $('#table1 tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td><a data-table="' + this.name + '">' + this.name + '</a></td></tr>'); 
});

$(document).on('click','[data-table]', function(){
  var link = $(this),
      tableName = link.attr('data-table');

  console.log(tableName);

  // do your ajax call with tableName
  // $.ajax({ ....
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<table id="table2">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsbin.com/jicihohama/edit?html,js,console,output

**Notes:**

1. > The page should then refresh and display the data

   By refresh you mean ajax "refresh"? Otherwise why you need an ajax?
2. You can't put `td` in `tbody` so you need to add a row (`tr`) too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One last thing, the data in table2, I thought'd be replaced by the new data, but it hasn't. Any idea how to delete the old data without deleting the table. I've tried things like: document.getElementById("table2").deleteTHead();

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can do `$('#table2').html('')` it will delete all the html in `#table2`. In that way, you can delete only `thead` or `tbody` content if you want. Savvy?